# How to downgrade iOS to previous version?

Tags: ios, downgrade

I really need to downgrade from **iOS 9** to **iOS 8** on my iPad Mini. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the firmware signing window has since closed for iOS 8.4.1 (as well as all earlier iOS builds for your device), so it should not be possible.

Source: https://ipsw.me/8.4.1